# How do I dynamically change the page title on a Delphi TMS Web Core Website?

Tags: delphi, browser, page-title, tms-web-core

I have a website with various frames that get shown/hidden depending on what item is chosen on the left menu as can be seen here:

[image: Roselt Developer Tools - Web Version]

When I click on an item on the left-hand side menu, I want to change the browser tab page title to match that of the item chosen.

How can I change the page title dynamically in run-time via Delphi code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `document` class from the `Web` unit and change the `title` public variable on the `document` class:

```
document.title := 'Your new page title';
```

Comment: Another thing in [JS/DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title) that exists for 25+ years - again you just rediscover what every website creator already knows.